# Flutter audio player - how to go to the specific page without all go back opened page one by one?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, audio-player

I am making a music player using Flutter and 'audio player' and I want to have 'previous' and 'next' button to play previous and next music.

Currently, I have sepearated classes for each music and when I connected them with 'Navigator.push' to show previous and next music easily.

But problem is for example, when I click B music in the music list and, in B music player page, there are previous and next buttons.

Previous button leads to A music page and next button leads to C music page. When I navigate pages with those buttons, route, for example, can be something like music list->B->C->B->A->B.

And then if I click 'back' button on the app bar which was created because of stateful widget itself, it doesn't go back to music list but goes all pages I accessed back one by one like B->A->B->C->B->music list.
I want it to go to music list directly.

So I am wondering whether I need to put all musics in one class not all sepearated classes or I need to changes the 'navigation' function.
But I'm not sure what solution actually works.
Could someone help me with this? Thank you

Below is the code of one music

```
class Music1 extends StatefulWidget {
      const Music1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Music1> createState() => _Music1State();
}

class _Music1State extends State<Music1> {
  //setting the project url
  String img_cover_url =
      "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a7/a9/cb/a7a9cbcefc58f5b677d8c480cf4ddc5d.jpg";
  late AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
  Duration _duration = new Duration();
  Duration _position = new Duration();
  bool isPlaying = false;
  bool isPaused = false;
  bool isLoop = false;

  void initPlayer() async {
    await advancedPlayer.setSource(AssetSource("forest.mp3"));
    advancedPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((d) {setState(() {
      _duration = d;
    }); });
    advancedPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((p) {setState(() {
      _position = p;
    }); });
  }

  //init the player
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    advancedPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    initPlayer();

  }

  @override
  void changeToSecond(int second) {
    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: second);
    advancedPlayer.seek(newDuration);
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Musics for Kids", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Itim",fontSize: 25)),),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            height: 300.0,
            width: 300.0,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/forest.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 28, sigmaY: 28),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              //setting the music cover
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/forest.jpg",
                  width: 250.0,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              const Text(
                "Forest",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36, letterSpacing: 6,  fontFamily: "Itim"),
              ),
              //Setting the seekbar
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30.0, //50
              ),
              Row( //problem part - previous and next buttons
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                       Navigator.push(context,
                           MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                             return const Music0();
                           })
                       );
                     }, 
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context)=> MusicList(),
                      ),
                          (route) => true,
                    ),
                    child: Text("Previous", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 200),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return const Music2();
                          })
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text("Next", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                ],

              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20.0, //50
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    _position.toString().split(".")[0],
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Slider.adaptive(
                    onChanged: (value){},
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                    value:_position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                    onChangeEnd: (double value){
                      setState((){
                        changeToSecond(value.toInt());
                        value = value;
                      });
                      advancedPlayer.pause();
                      advancedPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: value.toInt()));
                      advancedPlayer.resume();
                    },

                    activeColor: Colors.white,
                  ),

                  Text(
                    _duration.toString().split(".")[0],
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 60.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white38),
                    ),
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTapDown: (details) {
                        advancedPlayer.setPlaybackRate(0.5);
                      },
                      onTapUp: (details) {
                        advancedPlayer.setPlaybackRate(1);
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.fast_rewind_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 60.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                        color: Colors.black87,
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink),
                      ),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () async{
                          if (isPlaying) {
                            await advancedPlayer.pause();
                            setState((){
                              isPlaying = false;
                            });
                          } else {
                            await advancedPlayer.resume();
                            setState((){
                              isPlaying = true;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          isPlaying ? Icons.pause: Icons.play_arrow,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 60.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white38),
                    ),
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTapDown: (details) {
                        advancedPlayer.setPlaybackRate(2);
                      },
                      onTapUp: (details) {
                        advancedPlayer.setPlaybackRate(1);
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.fast_forward_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***: if you don't want the option I gave below, you could do this, and it will pop the screens until you reach the right screen:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/example'));
```

**An alternative:**

I think I didn't uderstand very well, but do you really need to each music be a different screen? Because you could make only one Music class, and just one screen for the player, and just move between the musics.

You could just setup a list of musics, and functions to move between one from another. Without having to make many different screens for each.

Example of Music Class:

```
class Music {
  String imgCoverUrl;
  Duration duration;
  String assetSource;

  Music({
    required this.imgCoverUrl,
    required this.duration,
    required this.assetSource,
  });
}
```

Example of the screen with functions:

```
class MusicPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MusicPlayerScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MusicPlayerScreen> createState() => _MusicPlayerScreenState();
}

class _MusicPlayerScreenState extends State<MusicPlayerScreen> {
  // variable to keep track of which music is playing right now
  int selectedMusicIndex = 0;

  // list of your musics, so you can move between one and another
  List<Music> myMusics = [
    Music(imgCoverUrl: 'cover_1.png', duration: Duration(seconds: 10), assetSource: 'myFolder/song1.mp3'),
    Music(imgCoverUrl: 'cover_2.png', duration: Duration(seconds: 10), assetSource: 'myFolder/song2.mp3'),
    Music(imgCoverUrl: 'cover_2.png', duration: Duration(seconds: 10), assetSource: 'myFolder/song3.mp3'),
  ];

  // function to move to the next music, verifying if have any music after the actual one
  void nextMusic() {
    if (selectedMusicIndex + 1 < myMusics.length) {
      setState(() {
        selectMusicIndex++;
      });
    }
  }

  // function to move to the previous music, verifying if isn't the first music
  void previousMusic() {
    if (selectMusic != 0) {
      setState(() {
        selectMusicIndex--;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Then you just use the following the get each music attributes:

```
myMusics[selectedMusicIndex].imgCoverUrl;
myMusics[selectedMusicIndex].duration;
myMusics[selectedMusicIndex].assetSource;
```